# sum the values of each row from a specific column in csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I can't find how to add all the value from the 3rd column to get the result in a new csv file with the first and second column.

lines can have variable values from 1 to 7, the addition will be ignored if there is a value or character other than 0.5 ,1 or 2

**Sample of the csv file :**

```
323|2013-06-03 00:00:00|0|0|0
323|2013-06-03 01:00:00|1|
323|2013-06-03 02:00:00|1|0|0.5|86
323|2013-06-03 03:00:00|1|0|0.5|0
323|2013-06-03 04:00:00|0
323|2013-06-03 05:00:00|0|0|0.5|0
323|2013-06-03 06:00:00|0
323|2013-06-03 07:00:00|1|0|0.5|2
323|2013-06-03 08:00:00|0|0.5
```

**what I'm looking for :**

```
323|2013-06-03 00:00:00|0
323|2013-06-03 01:00:00|1
323|2013-06-03 02:00:00|1.5
323|2013-06-03 03:00:00|1.5
323|2013-06-03 04:00:00|0
323|2013-06-03 05:00:00|0.5
323|2013-06-03 06:00:00|0
323|2013-06-03 07:00:00|3.5
323|2013-06-03 08:00:00|0.5
```

Comment: won't the 3rd row would be `323|2013-06-03 02:00:00|87.5`

Comment: if the values are different of 0.5 , 1 and 2 they are ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `csv` module. Note this gives a list of lists, with the final value in each sublist a `float`. You will require some additional logic to write your csv file from the list of lists. I leave that as an exercise.

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""323|2013-06-03 00:00:00|0|0|0
323|2013-06-03 01:00:00|1|
323|2013-06-03 02:00:00|1|0|0.5|86
323|2013-06-03 03:00:00|1|0|0.5|0
323|2013-06-03 04:00:00|0
323|2013-06-03 05:00:00|0|0|0.5|0
323|2013-06-03 06:00:00|0
323|2013-06-03 07:00:00|1|0|0.5|2
323|2013-06-03 08:00:00|0|0.5""")

L = []
with mystr as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter='|')
    for i, j, *k in reader:
        L.append([i, j, sum(i for i in map(float, filter(None, k)) if i in {0.5, 1, 2})])
```

**Result**

```
print(L)

[['323', '2013-06-03 00:00:00', 0.0],
 ['323', '2013-06-03 01:00:00', 1.0],
 ['323', '2013-06-03 02:00:00', 1.5],
 ['323', '2013-06-03 03:00:00', 1.5],
 ['323', '2013-06-03 04:00:00', 0.0],
 ['323', '2013-06-03 05:00:00', 0.5],
 ['323', '2013-06-03 06:00:00', 0.0],
 ['323', '2013-06-03 07:00:00', 3.5],
 ['323', '2013-06-03 08:00:00', 0.5]]
```

Comment: it return me an error : `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0 *'`
because some value aren't float in my csv

Comment: @Zenix, That's a new, different problem. You will need to provide a [mcve] in [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).